# (WooCommerce) Check if customer has made more than a certain number of orders or spent a certain amount?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way I can set a conditional statement to show a message to customers that have already made a certain number of orders or spent more than a certain amount of money on my store?

I basically want to offer a site-wide discount for valued customers, which I have already set up a system for, but ideally I'd like to show a form where users can apply for this discount, but to prevent everyone from applying I'd like to only show it to repeat customers.

Comment: Number of orders would be relatively simple I think. Order are just a custom post type `shop_order` so it's straight forward to use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to query for orders.

Comment: Ah, I wondered where the orders were stored - didn't think to look in wp_posts. Could you possibly link me to an example or help me out with a way of querying "if the user has made more than x amount of shop_order post types?" Also wow, a response from the one and only helgatheviking! I've lost count of how many times I've seen your name pop up on the Wordpress forums when troubleshooting problems. Thanks for the countless times you've helped me indirectly in the past!

Comment: @helgatheviking I just found [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/display-text-if-current-user-has-written-1-or-more-posts-in-a-custom-post-type) - Can the reply from MikeSchinkel be modified so instead of saying "if this user has created one or more posts" (return (count($result->posts)!=0);) I can ask "if this user has more than 5 posts"? I'm sure this is easy enough but my PHP knowledge is rather limited.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. :) See my answer below which is somewhat similar to the answer you l inked me to, but takes some WooCommerce-specific stuff into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that we can steal... er borrow... a query for orders right out of the [WooCommerce source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php#L16-22). We just need to modify the `posts_per_page` parameter to `-1` so that it will query *all* posts.

This has the potential to chew up resources... so 1. I suggest only running it for logged in users. 2. Maybe only retrieve the number of posts you want to limit your coupon to (aka... 5 orders gets you a discount, only retrieve 5 posts) and 3. possibly even cache the value either in a transient or maybe even keep track of it as user meta. That last one is a bit trickier than I want to get into now so

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $number_of_orders = 10;
    
    $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
        'numberposts' => $number_of_orders,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
    ) ) );

    if ( $customer_orders && count( $customer_orders > $number_of_orders ) ){
        // whoa you've got more than 10 orders
    }

}
```

**2024-04-05** Updated to use `wc_get_orders()` which will be compatible with High Performance Order Storage.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $number_of_orders = 10;

    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'status'      => array( 'wc-completed' ), // Remove as all statuses are returned by default.
        'limit'       => 11, // Default is posts_per_page setting.
    ) );

    if ( $customer_orders && count( $customer_orders > $number_of_orders ) ) {
        // Whoa you've got more than 10 orders.
    }

}
```

For additional [`wc_get_orders()` parameters see the documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#parameters).

Comment: Thank you! Good tip with the $number_of_orders too to reduce the resource usage (if I understood that correctly). I wasn't expecting to have this solved so quickly, so thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. You *may* want to remove the filter, but I'll leave that to you.